# If condition for empty list

Tags: apex, community

I am generating a link here.

I want to check if nothing in my list is empty and then generate a link.

I am not sure if code is right because Experience__c in exp list can return nothing (empty). DO not know what to do in case Experience__c will return empty

```
public static String expidVal {
    public get {
        return Constants.experienceID;
    }
    public set;
}

public static String purposeValue {
    public get;
    public set;
}

public static String usernameValue {
    public get;
    public set;
}

public static String expID {
    public get;
    public set;
}

public static String urlJWT {
    get {
        List <Experience_Settings__mdt> exp =  [SELECT Magic_Link_Extension__c, Experience__c 
                                                                FROM Experience_Settings__mdt 
                                                                WHERE Experience__c =: expID LIMIT 1];
        String language = [SELECT LanguageLocaleKey FROM User WHERE Username =: usernameValue LIMIT 1].LanguageLocaleKey;
        if (exp.size() > 0 && urlJWT == null && usernameValue != null && exp[1].Experience__c != null && exp[1].Experience__c == expID && exp[0].Magic_Link_Extension__c) {
            urlJWT = expID +'/logme?token=' + JWTGenerator.generateJWT(usernameVal, expidVal, purposeValue) + '&lang='+language;
        return urlJWT;
    } else { 
            urlJWT = expID + '/logme?token=' + JWTGenerator.generateJWT(usernameVal, expidVal, purposeValue) + '&lang=en_GB';
        return urlJWT;
    }    
       } 
    set;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using **Experience__c =: expID** in your query where **expId** is never empty then **Experience__c** in your query will never be empty.

So you can directly use filter in your SOQL query to check if Magic_Link_Extension__c !=null && Experience__c =: expID.

You can use **isEmpty()** function to check if your list is empty and **String.isBlank(yourStringVaribale)** to check if your String is white space, empty (''), or null

In if condition I have used **!exp.isEmpty()** to check if your **exp** list is not empty and **String.isBlank(urlJWT)** to check if **urlJWT** is blank/empty and  **!String.isBlank(usernameValue)** to check if **usernameValue** is not blank/empty.

```
get {
    List <Experience_Settings__mdt> exp =  [SELECT Magic_Link_Extension__c, Experience__c 
                                                            FROM Experience_Settings__mdt 
                                                            WHERE Magic_Link_Extension__c!=null AND Experience__c =: expID LIMIT 1];
    String language = [SELECT LanguageLocaleKey FROM User WHERE Username =: usernameValue LIMIT 1]?.LanguageLocaleKey;
    if (!exp.isEmpty() && String.isBlank(urlJWT) && !String.isBlank(usernameValue)) {
        urlJWT = expID +'/logme?token=' + JWTGenerator.generateJWT(usernameVal, expidVal, purposeValue) + '&lang='+language;
    return urlJWT;
} else { 
        urlJWT = expID + '/logme?token=' + JWTGenerator.generateJWT(usernameVal, expidVal, purposeValue) + '&lang=en_GB';
    return urlJWT;
}    
   }
```

However, if in any case **expId** is empty then you can add one if condition before your query to check if expId is not Empty.

```
get {
if(!String.isEmpty(expID)){
  List <Experience_Settings__mdt> exp =  [SELECT Magic_Link_Extension__c, Experience__c 
                                                            FROM Experience_Settings__mdt 
                                                            WHERE Magic_Link_Extension__c!=null AND Experience__c =: expID LIMIT 1];
    String language = [SELECT LanguageLocaleKey FROM User WHERE Username =: usernameValue LIMIT 1]?.LanguageLocaleKey;
    if (!exp.isEmpty() && String.isBlank(urlJWT) && !String.isBlank(usernameValue)) {
        urlJWT = expID +'/logme?token=' + JWTGenerator.generateJWT(usernameVal, expidVal, purposeValue) + '&lang='+language;
    return urlJWT;
} else { 
        urlJWT = expID + '/logme?token=' + JWTGenerator.generateJWT(usernameVal, expidVal, purposeValue) + '&lang=en_GB';
    return urlJWT;
} 
}
else{
  //do something
}
}
```

Hope this will help you!